Plugged a Japanese Nintendo 64 into UK mains, heard a snap and saw smoke come out of power supply. Is console ok?
So very, very stupidly I assumed Japanese voltage is same as UK voltage and happily plugged my recently purchased Japanese Nintendo 64 into the UK mains. I heard a snapping sound and then saw some smoke come out of the area around the power supply. I immediately realised what had happened and on checking the power supply voltage it was indeed different and much lower to that of the UK (100 versus 240). I've ordered a replacement UK-compatible power supply, but I'm worried if the console itself is okay? I suspect the Japanese power supply is definitely out of commission (and a lesson learned there too about making assumptions).

I'm not sure there is any way you can know for sure, until you get a new PSU and try it.

Got a proper UK power supply today and thankfully the console itself still worked. If you made the same mistake as me, but you had the power off when you plugged it into the mains, then at least in my case it seems that spares the console, even if it fries the power supply itself.

To be honest... I think you got lucky!

Gonna guess its a hertz thing; like NA is 60 hrz, EU is 50 hrz; maybe japan is not like the UK, and whatever plug converter you are using is not converting that hertz difference. Console gets unexpected amount of power, and the power supply explodes.

Yep, just checked; japan is half and half, one half is 50hertz, the other 60. Also my quick googling is telling me europe is 220 volts, japan is 100. So a voltage difference might also do it

@Fredy31 no, it's the massive voltage difference. All a frequency difference might do is affect timings, which on an N64 it doesn't.
